# MQTT Data Formatting of JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x, formatting

I am receiving the following JSON string over MQTT and want to extract the float values only.

The data in the str format, should I change the sending format over MQTT?

'{"data": [-0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18287938, -0.0929368, 0.18287938, 0.07806691, 0.18287938, 0.17843866, 0.18287938, 0.28252788, 0.1848249, 0.37174721]}'

I only want to deal with the float arrays, but not finding the way to get it from the str objects.

Could someone help?

Kind regards
arun

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python here's a way

```
import json
data_string = '{"data": [-0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18385214, -0.0929368, 0.18287938, -0.0929368, 0.18287938, 0.07806691, 0.18287938, 0.17843866, 0.18287938, 0.28252788, 0.1848249, 0.37174721]}'

#covert to Python
json_data = json.loads(data_string)

#extract the value 'data'
data = json_data["data"]
```